# How to only scrape specific part of text in element with bs4 and selenium?

Tags: selenium, beautifulsoup

I am trying to scrape a verification code sent to an email with BeatifulSoup4 and paste it into a verification field using selenium. This is the code that I use to extract the text inside of the element:

```
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source)
number_code = soup.find(class_="sms-text").text
verification_field = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
verification_field.send_keys(number_code)
```

However this will scrape all the text inside the element and not only the verification code I need. Can anyone tell how I can cut out the part of the text which I dont need so that I only get the number code?

PS: this was my very first post here and Im a complete newbie so please take it easy on me :)

Comment: Update the question with the HTML of the element containing the verification code.

Answer (score 2):

What I understand is that

```
verification_field = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
```

gives you the entire text and you just need an specific part. Well, you can use strings methods in order to clean the text.
For example if the text is "Your verification code is #####" and the part you want is always at the end of the sentence, you can use

```
verification_field = driver.find_element_by_name("q")
verification_field.replace("Your verification code is ", "")
```

This will bring you back just the code that you need to type using selenium